# Java Scanning to Line End

Tags: java, loops, line, java.util.scanner

I am trying to scan just one whole in in a file using the `Scanner`.

The problem is I need to write a loop that only scans the one line.

For example the line is:

```
Hello world it is nice out
```

I want it to save that whole sentence in a `String` without continuing on and reading the rest of the file. Therefore:

```
while(charscan.hasNext()) {
    String test= charscan.next() + " ";        
}
```

Does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `charscan.nextLine`?

Comment: You will be a much more productive Java programmer if you get used to consulting the [Javadoc of the classes you are trying to use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It's a well documented language, take advantage of that fact.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(charscan.hasNext()){
        String test= charscan.nextLine() + " ";
        break;

  }
```

If you are interested with only one line and don't want to use a loop, then use an `if` statement instead i.e

```
if(charscan.hasNext()){
    String test = charscan.nextLine() + " ";
}
```